# Opening folders and files in python scripting

Tags: python, file, directory

I have this piece of code:

```
import os
def find(name):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk("Desktop/"):
        if name in files:
             os.startfile("Desktop/", name, ".exe")


def findFold(name):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk("Desktop/"):
        if name in files:
            os.startfile("This PC/", name)

..............
    if OpenFile.lower() == "music" or OpenFile.lower() == "music folder":
        findFold("Music")
..............
    elif OpenFile.lower() == "wolf team" or OpenFile.lower() == "wolfteam":
        find("Wolfteam")
```

The OpenFile is a string which is the input of the user(the name of the file or folder.
The program doesn't open the files and folders that I want it to open.

I looked in the internet and this is how people said it is and working..
Can somebody help please?

Comment: "doesn't open .. what I want it to open": What do you want, and what does it do instead?

Comment: In the findFold method, I think you should change `if name in files` by `if name in dirs`

Comment: The file I want it to open is what I give OpenFile var as an input(it is a raw_input variable) . Well actually what the program does is just going over itself, and chronologically it is alright, how ever after I give it an input of the file or folder I want to open, it is just moving on and nothing is being opened..

Comment: @avenet        I changed it to dirs but still no folder is being opened after I give the folder name as an input. As well as the files. Wolfteam and Music are just 2 examples for folder and file I would like to open

Comment: Are you on windows ? `startfile` don't work on other platform.

Comment: I am using Windows, yes

Comment: @ErezProductions is there any output for your program? Does it fail?

Comment: @avenet     Nope the console says everything is ok. The program algorithm is working fine, the only problem is that nothing is being opened

Comment: @ErezProductions Are you sure a folder named exactly "Music" exists on your Desktop and a file named "Wolfteam", (not Wolfteam.exe) exists?

Comment: Yes. Music is the default folder in every computer. It can be found in This PC --> near the desktop, documents and etc folders

Comment: Yes, I understand, but remember that Music folder is not inside the Desktop (at least by default, it would be located in somewhere like C:\<Your_User>\, alongside with Desktop). If the Music folder is not inside the Desktop your program won't be able to find it...

Comment: @avenet         I know. you can see that in the findFold function, it is written "This PC", and not "Desktop"

Comment: @ErezProductions I think findFold function search inside the Desktop folder, as you do in `os.walk("Desktop/")`

Comment: @avenet        how is that?

Comment: `os.walk("Desktop/")` returns an iterator over the files and folders names contained on the Desktop folder, Did you meant to search inside another folder?

Comment: @avenet         That is in the function Find.  in the function FindFold it is written "This PC"

Answer (score 0):

It is very unclear of what you are trying to accomplish, however, I believe you have a backslash where you want a forward slash if you are trying to invoke applications on a Windows based file system

e.g. I would change

```
os.startfile("This PC/", name)
```

to

```
os.startfile("This PC/{}".format(name))
```

I also suggest you look into the PEP 8 coding conventions for Python, and use their suggestions for readable code.  Namely:

**look into adding docstrings to your methods**

```
def fileFold(name):
    '''
    why this method exists
    '''
```

**do not hard code your paths but have them be variables**

```
def findFold(name, prefix="\Desktop\", suffix=".exe")
```

**wrap your activities in Try Except blocks**

```
try:
    os.startfile("{}{}{}".format(prefix, name, suffix))
except OSError as err:
    print("Unable to invoke application {}: {}".format(name, err))
```

Comment: I changed it to os.startfile("This PC/{}".format(name)) how ever it still doesn't work. Can you be more specific on what else you want to know and I will give you that information